# How to implement interactive scrollbar to RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar, android-scrollview

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image: https://thumbs.gfycat.com/SpeedyThunderousHerculesbeetle-size_restricted.gif]

That's my app drawer. You see how you can slide/drag the scrollbar up and down for faster results as opposed to sliding the screen itself?

Is there any way to  implement this to a Recycler View? I have this as an attribute to my recyclerView on xml but all that does is displays the scrollbar. You can't actually interact with the scrollbar itself.

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Comment: you can try this lib https://github.com/turing-tech/MaterialScrollBar?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2441

Comment: or this [https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller](https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller)

Comment: Here is more simple and more common example https://github.com/rno/Android-ScrollBarPanel

Answer (score 0):

You can use fastscrolling feature of support library 26. It provides following attributes to RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable">
```

more info in [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/fast-scrolling-with-recyclerview-2b89d4574688) post, or in this sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/shaishavgandhi05/FastScrolling)